# Can I replace the original computer owner's Microsoft account without reinstalling Win 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

I received a used computer.  They gave me a PIN to access it.  He has a Microsoft account on it.  The Win 10 has a digital key.  I don't know the password for the Microsoft account and don't know how to contact the original owner.

Can I remove this account and set up my own without reinstalling Win 10?  I don't have the original disks or key.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 does not require that you have the key while reinstalling as long as it was activated at least once as its associated and transferred as part of the machine unless it was a version of windows that does not allow transfer in which case you'd need your own license as it was never transferred to you.

I suggest either making a backup of the hdd or using a new hdd and simply see if windows activates on its own. If it doesn't you can always go back. Since you don't know the state of the computer given to you it may not even be valid or transferable to begin with. At that point you could investigate other options further.

Edit: You can download windows here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Your choices are either Home or Pro. If its Education or Enterprise you don't have a license to use it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling may be smarter as you are probably want to reformat anyway. Note that in windows 10, if windows is activated without the use of a crack, and between reinstalls, hardware doesn't change, nor is it the enterprise version of windows, it will reactivate.

But in case you really want to keep the installation, yes, you can do so.

Note, you do need to have a windows installer, preferably windows 10, but windows 8 or 7 should work too.

You boot into windows setup and then press SHIFT-F10 at the first screen. This should open a command prompt window.

From here run the following 2 commands:

```
copy c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe~
copy c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe
```

Reboot the computer back to the windows 10 logon screen. Now, locate the Ease of Access button in the bottom left corner. If done correctly, it should popup a command prompt window.

In this window, type the following commands:

```
net user NewUser * /add
<enter a new password for this user, empty passwords allowed>
net localgroup administrators NewUser /add
```

*Replace NewUser with any username you want*

Reboot the pc and once more boot into the windows setup.

Press SHIFT-F10 once more to open a command prompt and type the following commands:

```
copy c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe~ c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe
```

Reboot back into windows, now you should be able to see 2 users. The NewUser one should have the password you specified and should give you access. From here, you can remove the old user account, and use windows.

Do note, that last boot into setup is to make your system secure again. If you decide to leave that in, any hacker can do serious damage to your pc.